# How do I make Jackson ObjectMapper use my custom deserializer (applied with contentUsing)?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am having trouble getting jackson to respect my custom JsonDeserializer. The situation is, I have a class `MyClass` that contains a list of another class, `OtherClass`,  that is outside of my control (so I can't annotate it). This `OtherClass` class is an interface with multiple implementations. I don't care what the original `OtherClass` was, I want them to always deserialize as `BasicOtherClass`.

Here is what I have:

```java
@Getter
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("otherclasses")
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=OtherClassSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=OtherClassDeserializer.class)
    private List<OtherClass> otherClasses;

    public MyClass(
            @JsonProperty("otherclasses")
            @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=OtherClassDeserializer.class)
            List<OtherClass> otherClasses) {
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
    }
}


public static class OtherClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OtherClass> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(OtherClass otherClass, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("name", otherClass.getName());
        gen.writeStringField("value", otherClass.getValue());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    /** This method is required when default typing is enabled */
    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(
            OtherClass otherClass, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer)
                    throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForScalar(value, gen, OtherClass.class);
        serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForScalar(value, gen);
    }
}


public static class OtherClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Header> {

    @Override
    public Header deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        if (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to parse OtherClass from json");
        }

        String name = null;
        String value = null;

        while (p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            String key = p.getText();
            p.nextToken();
            String val = p.getText();
            if (key.equals("name")) {
                name = val;
            } else if (key.equals("value")) {
                value = val;
            }
        }

        return new BasicOtherClass(name, value);
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to get to work:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
OtherClass otherClass = new BufferedOtherClass("name value");
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(Lists.newArrayList(otherClass));
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);

// json == ["com.bschlenk.MyClass", {"otherclass": ["java.util.ArrayList", [["com.other.OtherClass", {"name": "name", "value", "value"}]]]}]
```

But when I try to read that json back into `MyClass`, it fails:

```java
MyClass parsed = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);

// com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
// Can not construct instance of org.apache.http.Header, problem:
// abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types,
// have custom deserializer,
// or be instantiated with additional type information
```

This works when I don't have type information enabled. However, it is other code that is serializing `MyClass` that I don't have control of, and it has type info on.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Why doesn't `mapper.readValue` use my custom `JsonDeserializer` class? Is this by design?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question?